# how to output the array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
   [menu-162] => Array
    (
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [title] => example1
            )

        [href] => node/13
        [title] => test1
    )

[menu-219] => Array
    (
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [title] => example2
            )

        [href] => node/30
        [title] => test2
    )

)
```

If I assign the above array to a variable named `$hello`, now, I want to use a loop only output the `menu-162`, `menu-219`.

If I want to only output the attributes title value, if I only want to output the href's value.

How do I write these loops?

Comment: This is **really** basic stuff. Have you tried anything? Looked at the [`foreach` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)? Tried to loop through the array and `print_r` on each iteration to see what you can work with?

Comment: please add an example of what you would expect the output to be look like

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($hello as $item) {
  $attr = $item['attributes']['title'];
  $href = $item['href'];
  echo "attr is {$attr}";
  echo "href is {$href}";
}
```

That should output the attr and href.

Answer (score 0):

You can access titles value within the attributes array like so: `$hello['menu-162']['attributes']['title']` and for any other 'menu' you can substitute `menu-162` with the appropriate menu-number combination. As for the `href` a simple `$hello['menu-162']['href']`

As for a loop to access both the values a simple `foreach` should suffice:

```
foreach($hello as $value) {
    echo $value['attributes']['title'];
    echo $value['href'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($hello as $key => $value) {
    switch($key) {
        case 'menu-162':
        case 'menu-219':
            if($value['href'] && $value['attribute'] && $value['attribute']['title']) {
                $href = $value['href'];
                $attr = $value['attribute']['title'];
            }
        break;
        default:
            continue; //didn't find it
        break;
    }
}
```

If you do not need the specific menu finding, remove the switch statement. If you do need the specific ids using this is the more scalable solution, and is faster than a nested if. It will also not create notices for variables that don't exist and will only return if both attribute title, and href exist.